# Is there a way to simplify conditional rendering while using multiple useState?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I have 3 different audio files displaying on a page. I would like to display different texts depending on which audio file has been played.

Here is what I have so far: https://btangsp.github.io/essae_rating/

However, the code I have isn't really elegant in my opinion. Is there a way to make it more compact but still readable?

Right now my code is roughly in the form of the following:

```
const [refAudioEnded, setRefAudioEnded] = useState(false);
const [firstAudioEnded, setFirstAudioEnded] = useState(false);
const [secondAudioEnded, setSecondAudioEnded] = useState(false);

if (secondAudioEnded) {
    // display text A
} else if (firstAudioEnded) {
    // display text B
} else if (refAudioEnded) {
    // display text C
}
```

EDIT: Here it is in detail:

```
const [refEnded, setRefEnded] = useState(false);
const [firstEnded, setFirstEnded] = useState(false);
const [secondEnded, setSecondEnded] = useState(false);

function Task_Page_Conditional(taskInstruction, shuffledFiles, choice, setChoice, audioRef, refEnded, audioEnded, setAudioEnded) {
    return (
        <div className="section col-all">
            {taskInstruction}
            <AudioRadioButtonGroup name={'test-abx'} 
                files={shuffledFiles} 
                choice={choice}
                setChoice={setChoice}
                audioRefs={audioRef}
                refEnded={refEnded}
                audioEnded={audioEnded}
                setAudioEnded={setAudioEnded}
                />
        </div>
    );
}

let taskInstruction = null;
let task_pt1 = null;
const shuffledFiles = Shuffle(['noisy/' + shuffledData[index].noisy, 'enhanced/' + shuffledData[index].enhanced]);

if (secondEnded) {
    taskInstruction = (
        <ReactMarkdown source={text.audio_group.question}/>
    );
    task_pt1 = Task_Page_Conditional(taskInstruction, shuffledFiles, choice, setChoice, 
            [audioRef_2, audioRef_3], refEnded, secondEnded, setSecondEnded);
} else if (firstEnded) {
    taskInstruction = (
        <ReactMarkdown source={text.audio_group.second_audio}/>
    );
    task_pt1 = Task_Page_Conditional(taskInstruction, shuffledFiles, choice, setChoice, 
            [audioRef_2, audioRef_3], refEnded, secondEnded, setSecondEnded);
} else if (refEnded) {
    taskInstruction = (
        <ReactMarkdown source={text.audio_group.first_audio}/>
    );
    task_pt1 = Task_Page_Conditional(taskInstruction, [shuffledFiles[0]], choice, setChoice, 
            [audioRef_2], refEnded, firstEnded, setFirstEnded);
}
```

Comment: I think so, but a good solution would require seeing more context around the code - can you show more of the component, including `// display text A`?

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I just added a section with more detail. It's a bit messy though, which is what I want to solve but I'm not really sure where to begin. @CertainPerformance

Comment: Brian, You are maintaining 3 different states. Do you need 3 states or it is actually a single state with 3 events? Will you ever have 2 of them together?

Comment: @MehulThakkar Actually, you bring up a good point. I think it's technically 1 state with 3 events/stages. So maybe it would be better to actually have the state be represented by a string or index rather than a boolean. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

@Brian As you have mentioned in the comment, if you can handle the 3 statuses in a single state then that will reduce the redundant states.

Here's the reformatted code using single state.

```js
const [state, setState] = useState('');

function Task_Page_Conditional(taskInstruction, shuffledFiles, choice, setChoice, audioRef, refEnded, audioEnded, setAudioEnded) {
    return (
        <div className="section col-all">
            {taskInstruction}
            <AudioRadioButtonGroup name={'test-abx'} 
                files={shuffledFiles} 
                choice={choice}
                setChoice={setChoice}
                audioRefs={audioRef}
                refEnded={refEnded}
                audioEnded={audioEnded}
                setAudioEnded={setAudioEnded}
                />
        </div>
    );
}

const getData = () => {
  let taskInstruction = null;
  let task_pt1 = null;
  const shuffledFiles = Shuffle(['noisy/' + shuffledData[index].noisy, 'enhanced/' + shuffledData[index].enhanced]);

  switch(state) {
    case 'taskInstruction': {
      taskInstruction = (
            <ReactMarkdown source={text.audio_group.question}/>
        );
      task_pt1 = Task_Page_Conditional(taskInstruction, shuffledFiles, choice, setChoice, 
                [audioRef_2, audioRef_3], refEnded, secondEnded, setSecondEnded);
      break;
    }
    case 'firstEnded': {
      taskInstruction = (
          <ReactMarkdown source={text.audio_group.second_audio}/>
      );
      task_pt1 = Task_Page_Conditional(taskInstruction, shuffledFiles, choice, setChoice, 
              [audioRef_2, audioRef_3], refEnded, secondEnded, setSecondEnded);
      break;
    }
    case 'refEnded': {
      taskInstruction = (
          <ReactMarkdown source={text.audio_group.first_audio}/>
      );
      task_pt1 = Task_Page_Conditional(taskInstruction, [shuffledFiles[0]], choice, setChoice, 
              [audioRef_2], refEnded, firstEnded, setFirstEnded);
      break;
    }
    default:
      // Any default case here
  }

  
  return {taskInstruction, task_pt1, shuffledFiles}
}

const {taskInstruction, task_pt1, shuffledFiles} = getData()
```